# how to make different index in vueJS

Tags: vue.js

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      CartList: {
        cartItems: [
          {
            id: 1
            quantity: 1
            total: 50000
            training:
            {
              id: 1,
              title: The Title ABCD,
              price: 50000,
              coverImage: "image.jpg"
            }
          },
          {
            id: 2
            quantity: 1
            total: 60000
            training:
            {
              id: 2,
              title: The Title DEFG,
              price: 60000,
              coverImage: "image.jpg"
            }
          },
        ]
      },
      details: [{
        name: null,
        email: null,
        phone: null
      }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div v-for="item in CartList.cartItems" :key="item.id" class="cartlist-detail">
    <div class="cartlist-detail-item--left">
        <img :src="constructImageUrl(item.training.coverImage)" class="cartlist-detail-item--left">

        <!-- :style="{backgroundImage: 'url(' + constructImageUrl(item.coverImage) + ')'}" -->
    </div>
    <div class="cartlist-detail-item--right">
        <div class="title">{{ item.training.title}}</div>
        <div class="harga">Rp. {{ item.training.price | formatRupiah }}</div>
        <div class="counter">
            <integer-plusminus v-model="item.quantity" :min="min" :max="max" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title"> Detail Data Pembeli </div>
    <div class="cartlist-detail" v-for="(item,index) in item.quantity" :key="item.id">
        <div class="totals">Pembeli ke {{item}}</div>
        <div>
            <div class="title">Nama pembeli*</div>
            <input v-model="details[index].name" placeholder="Masukan nama pembeli" class="nama" type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="title">Nomor HP pembeli*</div>
            <input v-model="details[index].phone" placeholder="Masukan nomor HP pembeli" class="phone" type="number">
            <!-- <div> {{details}} </div> -->
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="title">Email pembeli*</div>
            <input v-model="details[index].email" placeholder="Masukan email pembeli" class="email" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how to make a different index for my input?
if I input index 0 then another input index 0 will same value.

kindly help with my problem

for example i input name sasa then another name sasa will appear

noted: I have edited my code here, so let me know that make confused

I really appreciate and thank you who help me

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQYUA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue but failed to do so. My example below seems to work. Is there something I missed?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      item: {
        quantity: [{
            id: 1
          },
          {
            id: 2
          },
          {
            id: 3
          },

        ]
      },
      details: [{
          name: null,
          email: null,
          phone: null
        },
        {
          name: null,
          email: null,
          phone: null
        },
        {
          name: null,
          email: null,
          phone: null
        },
        {
          name: null,
          email: null,
          phone: null
        },
        {
          name: null,
          email: null,
          phone: null
        },
        {
          name: null,
          email: null,
          phone: null
        },
        {
          name: null,
          email: null,
          phone: null
        },
        {
          name: null,
          email: null,
          phone: null
        },
        {
          name: null,
          email: null,
          phone: null
        },
        {
          name: null,
          email: null,
          phone: null
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.cartlist-detail {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="title"> Detail Data Pembeli </div>
  
  <div class="cartlist-detail" v-for="(item,index) in item.quantity" :key="item.id">
    <div class="totals">Pembeli ke {{item}}</div>
    
    <div>
      <div class="title">Nama pembeli*</div>
      <input v-model="details[index].name" placeholder="Masukan nama pembeli" class="nama" type="text">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <div class="title">Nomor HP pembeli*</div>
      <input v-model="details[index].phone" placeholder="Masukan nomor HP pembeli" class="phone" type="number">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <div class="title">Email pembeli*</div>
      <input v-model="details[index].email" placeholder="Masukan email pembeli" class="email" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```